# why getnameinfo() retrieve repeated address?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Im using getnameinfo() function from the BSD socket API to get addresses from a host, i want get all kind of address available:

```
 struct addrinfo hints;
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_flags = AI_ALL;
  struct addrinfo *peer_address;
  if (getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &peer_address)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo() ERROR.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("Remote address(es):\n");
  struct addrinfo *address = peer_address;

  while((address = address->ai_next)) {
    char address_buffer[100];
    getnameinfo(address->ai_addr, address->ai_addrlen,
        address_buffer, sizeof(address_buffer), 0, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
    printf("\t> %s\n", address_buffer);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(peer_address);
```

and building and running this code i get that output:

```
$lookup google.com
Remote address(es):
   > 172.217.203.100
   > 172.217.203.100
   > 172.217.203.102
   > 172.217.203.102
   > 172.217.203.102
     .
     .
     .
   > 2607:f8b0:400c:c07::8a
   > 2607:f8b0:400c:c07::8a
   > 2607:f8b0:400c:c07::8a
```

why every IP address is printed two or three times?

Comment: It's not checking the result of `getnameinfo()` so some might be failing, leaving you with the previous entry's value. Also, doesn't this skip the *first* entry in the list?

Comment: ```getnameinfo()``` is fine, return 0, there is not the problem, but thanks, i must remember check the return value from every function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the effect of an overly-unspecified `hints` variable, which would normally narrow down the list to just what you're asking for.

When you ask for everything, it appears that for each IP address, there's an entry for tcp (`SOCK_STREAM`), udp (`SOCK_DGRAM`), plus just IP (`SOCK_RAW`), but in the case of just looking up IP addresses--as opposed to services--I don't see how this is useful.

Easy way to fix this is to update your hints:

```
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_flags = AI_ALL;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_RAW;   // ADD ME
```

Also, your loop does skip the first entry, so an alternate could be:

```
    for (struct addrinfo *address = peer_address
       ;  address != 0
       ;  address = address->ai_next )
    {
        // do stuff
```

A helpful reference: [What's the "hints" mean for the addrinfo name in socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755308/whats-the-hints-mean-for-the-addrinfo-name-in-socket-programming)

Comment: thanks Steve now all its very clear, i may be noted that if i print the service/port from the address, by the way only need specify the socket type and it works.

Comment: Hmmm, this answer was unaccepted - is it no longer correct?

Comment: yeah, is corret, was only my error, is accepted, thanks a lot Steve!.